# Place API- How to get the NearbyList of a Specific(Different) Location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I am integrated new place API and I am using the below method to get the nearest place list.

```
 private fun getNearestPlaceList(placesClient: PlacesClient) {
        val placeFields = listOf(Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.LAT_LNG)
        val request = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.builder(placeFields).build()
        placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener { response ->
            placeList.clear()
            response.placeLikelihoods.map { placeLikelihood -> placeLikelihood.place }
                    .filter { place -> !place.id.isNullOrEmpty() && !place.name.isNullOrEmpty() }
                    .forEach { place ->
                        val placeModel = PlaceModel(place.name!!, place.id!!)
                        placeList.add(placeModel)
                    }
            setAdapter(placeList)
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            if (exception is ApiException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.statusCode)
            }
        }
    }
```

The current API is only collecting the nearest location of my device current location. But My requirement is to get the nearest place of a Specific(Different) location. So Is it possible to input location info(Different Lat Long) to the API and get the nearest list of that location?. Currently, the API is automatically collecting the current location and it's sending a list of nearest places. Anyone have a solution, please update?

Comment: *I am using the below method to get the nearest place list* + *requirement is to get the nearest place* + *get the nearest list of that location* = ??? It is totally unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please edit your question so that it is clear.

Comment: @MrUpsidown: I have edited the question. My requirement is to get the nearest location list of a different place far away from my current location. Is that clear for you?

Comment: I don't know what comes with the Android API but you can certainly use the [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) web service from the Places API. Have a look at the [Client libraries](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/client-library) maybe...

Comment: for some location response.placeLikelihoods is empty!
for example Latitude : 42.563820
Longitude: -83.300232

Answer (score 2):

Getting the nearest places from a specific location (not the device's current location) is not currently available in the [Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place). To clarify, the `PlaceLikelihood`'s from the `FindCurrentPlaceResponse` are places where the device is likely to be located.

> The FindCurrentPlaceResponse contains a list of PlaceLikelihood
>   objects representing places where the device is likely to be located.
>   For each place, the result includes an indication of the likelihood
>   that the place is the right one. The list may be empty, if there is no
>   known place corresponding to the given device location.

As I understand your use-case, you can get a list of nearby places for a specific location through **Places API - [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)**.

> A Nearby Search lets you search for places within a specified area.
>   You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying
>   the type of place you are searching for.

Sample request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

There are also available open source client libraries that you can use for Google Maps Web Services. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/client-library).

Lastly, there is also an existing **feature request** for this in Google's Public Issue Tracker. I'd recommend you "star" it to receive updates.
           https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133276015

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am aware of this API, and my question is whether we can do it through Place SDK. Thanks!

Comment: This is a very clear and thorough answer. However, the two APIs - findCurrentPlace() in the Android SDK and Nearby Search in the http API - are not exactly the same. The first seems to do the job of predicting the likelihood that you are in the respective places for you (hence the name `PlaceLikelihood` in the response), which the second unfortunately does not. I also have a use case where I would need a findCurrentPlace(lat, lon), which does not exist though (perhaps, this is due to the fact that findCurrentPlace()'s algorithm uses more features than just (lat, lon) to predict likelihoods).